# Matching image names based on item numbers using string functions

Tags: excel, vba, csv

So I am iterating two columns of item numbers and image names, looking for matches based on several conditions. We first look to see if the matching item number has an image with the word **ROOM** in it, as we prefer to use the environment shot.

If it doesn't, then we need to look for an image matching the item number without ROOM, e.g. **ADR700C-28.jpg** and lastly if we don't find this, we need to fall back to one of several defaults. So for that item above (ADR700C-28) we will use **ADR700C-5.jpg**, **ADR700C-6.jpg**, and **ADR700C-8.jpg** in that order.

Here is what I have, problem is I'm having trouble doing this with the nested `Right()` and `Left()` string functions. Based on the expected output above, how to do with Select Case? Also I need the above string functions to account for image names that have a variable number characters.

Data Example:

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, arr(), r As Long, c As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    arr = ws.Range("A2:C" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    For r = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)

        For c = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)

            ' Having trouble with this piece ..

            Select Case True

            Case Right$(arr(c, 3), 9) = "-ROOM.jpg" And Left$(arr(c, 3), Len(arr(c, 3)) - 9) = arr(r, 1)
                arr(r, 2) = arr(c, 3)
                Exit For
            Case Right$(arr(c, 3), 6) = "-5.jpg" And Left$(arr(c, 3), Len(arr(c, 3)) - 6) = arr(r, 1)
                arr(r, 2) = arr(c, 3)
                Exit For
            Case Right$(arr(c, 3), 6) = "-6.jpg" And Left$(arr(c, 3), Len(arr(c, 3)) - 6) = arr(r, 1)
                arr(r, 2) = arr(c, 3)
                Exit For

            End Select

        Next

    Next
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ws.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)) = arr
End Sub
```

Comment: Difficult to follow this without a screenshot of the data going into `arr`

Comment: Updated, screenshot included. Thanks! Right now I'm not receiving expected output, in fact it's filling column B with the string ".jpg" which is very odd.

Comment: Could you add some examples of expected results too please?

Comment: Added, so you see the first two examples had "-ROOM.jpg" in the images and thus matched, whereas the last didn't have one and matched an image without "ROOM" - e.g. **NF133D-6SQ.jpg** So we want to see if a matching image has "-ROOM.jpg" suffix and if not, find image matching item name as a fallback.

Comment: @SJR: Updated, sorry the suffix **.jpg** was cutoff.

Comment: Are you saying the only results you get in B are ",jpg"? Can you comment out the On Error lines and try then.

Comment: Yes, I only am getting **.jpg** right now. I commented the `On Error` lines and am getting this error: *Run time Error '5'; Invalid procedure call or argument*

Comment: On which line ?

Comment: The first case after the initial `Select Case True` block: `Case Right$(arr(c, 3), 9) = "-ROOM.jpg" And Left$(arr(c, 3), Len(arr(c, 3)) - 9) = arr(r, 1)`

Comment: I just tested the sample of four rows and it worked for me (one result was different but there were no errors). Can you try just putting it into a new workbook and testing that?

Comment: Same problem unfortunately, does it matter if it's saved as a CSV file?

Comment: Now it's saying *Subscript out of range*

Comment: Possibly, can you try it in an Excel workbook with a sheet called "Sheet1".

Comment: Ok so your data are in a csv file but your code refers to `ThisWorkbook` which is the workbook containing the code. CSVs don't contain code.

Comment: Your screenshots don't help much: the third column is cut off so we can't see the full content, and the second screenshot doesn't seem to have any data in common with the first.  It would be much easier to help if we could see what you're working with and what the correct output should be based on the input.

Comment: I updated it, again the goal is to iterate through both columns, find matches based on the suffix of each image and place the matches adjacent to the corresponding item number in column B. The second image gives an idea of the output. If you have more questions let me know, thank you!

Comment: Your expected output is inconsistent with your stated problem with respect to '-6.jpg' as your output shows files with letters after the 6 but you state you only want files ending in '-6.jpg'. You have also referred to column B when your column letters are not indicated only inferred from your code. I presume you are looking for any images in the column heading 'image' where the 'sku' value appears in the name and you want to select the image names in an order of precedence. It would be good for you to make your stated example match your data.

Comment: Can you address my last comment please? If you put @ in front of a username they are alerted to your response.

Comment: @SJR: I tried it using filename "ThisWorkbook" and an .xlsx file but it still isn't working.

Comment: You'll need to save it as an xlsm file if it contains a macro.